# Java Regular Expression for extracting mentioned name in Tweeter message

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a small program that extract username mentioned in a Tweeter's message by using regular expression. However, part of the program is failing in some test cases. Basically, the regex pattern specified below is able to match text1 but not text2. Now, the regex pattern below is only meant to match a specific test case when the first character in the string is "@" followed by a valid username in tweeter. I think I must have misunderstood this regex and used it wrongly. Will someone be able to shed some light on this please?

```
String validTweetPattern1 = "^[@]((?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])[\\w-_]+)";
String text1 = "@mention";
String text2 = "@mention @hello";

System.out.println(Pattern.matches(validTweetPattern1, text1));  
System.out.println(Pattern.matches(validTweetPattern1, text2));  

Console Output:
True
False
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing exactly what you plan to do with the regex, I can suggest that you change the pattern the following:

```
String validTweetPattern1 = "(?:^|.*\\s+)[@]((?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])[\\w-_]+).*";
```

This identifies a Twitter hashtag as a string starting with an `@` symbol either at the very start of the string or in the middle of the string if preceded by whitespace.  You can check the demo below that email addresses are not being captured by this regex.  Your current pattern is searching for a hashtag at the very beginning of the string, and also doesn't allow for a space, followed by another tag, to appear after the first tag.

## Demo

Comment: yes, my current regex only search for a hashtag at the very beginning. In my program, I am actually using this regex to check if there is a hashtag at the beginning of the string. Otherwise, I will use another regex to search for any other hashtag in the body. 

The issue with your regex is it will also detect something like an email address as a valid twitter hashtag. Will this regex below be slightly more suitable?
    
"[\\W&&[^@]]*((?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])[\\w-_]+)[\\W&&[^@]]*"

Answer (score 0):

Pattern.matches() only returns true on an exact match. If you want to continue using it you will have to change your pattern to `"^[@]((?=.*[A-Za-z0-9])[\\w-_]+)\\s*.*"` this will add possible whitespace followed by possibly more characters.

Your other option is to use the matcher class with your current pattern.

```
    System.out.println(Pattern.compile(validTweetPattern1).matcher(text1).find());  
    System.out.println(Pattern.compile(validTweetPattern1).matcher(text2).find());
```

This will find an occurrence of the pattern in the text.